# how to call TrackPopupMenu function from managed vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, unmanaged, managed, vb6-migration

I am trying to call `TrackPopupMenu` function to display a menu at runtime from managed VB.NET code. 
Below is the error I am getting :

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'UeWIPopupX!UeWIPopupX.mDeclares::**TrackPopupMenu**' has unbalanced
>   the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does
>   not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
>   convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

Below is the declaration I am using for TrackPopupMenu function :

```
 <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Friend Function TrackPopupMenu(ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal wFlags As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nReserved As Integer, ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lprc As RECT) As Integer

End Function
```

Below is the code for calling `TrackPopupMenu` function :

```
 dim lpRc as RECT
 Dim tP As POINTAPI
 Dim lR as Integer  
 Dim lUn as Integer

 lUn = TPM_RIGHTBUTTON Or TPM_TOPALIGN Or TPM_LEFTALIGN Or TPM_RETURNCMD   
  tP.x = 50
  tP.y = 100
 'Here I am getting the error
 lR = TrackPopupMenu(m_ppMenu.Tools(1).hMenu, lUn, tP.x, tP.y, 0, m_hWndOwner, lpRC)
```

Below is the declaration for rectangle `RECT`:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Structure RECT
    Dim Left As Integer
    Dim Top As Integer
    Dim Right As Integer
    Dim Bottom As Integer
End Structure
```

All the arguments during call of TrackPopupMenu has some values.
I tried different callingConvention but still getting the error.

I am not able to solve this. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration is wrong.  The first argument is a handle to the menu, it must therefore be IntPtr.  The last argument is a *pointer* to RECT.  ByRef in VB.NET.  Since it isn't actually used, you are better off declaring it ByVal IntPtr so you don't need the RECT declaration.  Pass IntPtr.Zero in your call.  The return value is Boolean, not Integer.  Throw a Win32Exception if you get a False return.  Fix:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Friend Function TrackPopupMenu(ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal wFlags As Integer, _
    ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nReserved As Integer, _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ignored As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

There are some hints that you didn't get the menu right, hard to imagine how you came up with Long as the argument type.  Do note that this function is already ably wrapped in .NET, having to pinvoke it should be extremely rare.  TrackPopupMenu is already called by the .NET ContextMenu class.  The ContextMenuStrip class gives a more modern version of it with better rendering options.